# hide a element when i click outside

Tags: jquery, click, hide

i have an element in my page.

```
<div id="element">try</div>
```

I want hide it when i click in others elements in the page.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take advantage of bubbling here, like this:

```
$("#element").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $("#element").hide();
});
```

If you click *on* the `#element`, it stops the bubble (using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)) from going all the way up to `document` and firing it's `click` handler.  If anywhere else is clicked it *does* bubble up, and when the click reaches document, it hides `#element`.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that before